# MPI freezing during communications

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have installed openMPI on two nodes in an internal network in university. The nodes are able to ssh to each other without password. I tried the hello world MPI code and it works on both nodes when I run with mpirun -np 1 , but when I try mpirun -np 2 -machinefile nodes and run the code on both nodes, it freezes. I found that the problems is MPI_Send and MPI_Recv in the code. When I comment them and there is no communication in the code, it works perfectly, but when there is communication it does not work.

Probably there is an issue in connection between the nodes and I was wondering if anyone knows how can I find out what is wrong. BTW, I do not have sudo access.

Thanks

Comment: If you have any firewall on any of these nodes, you should disable them since SSH connectivity is not enough for MPI.

Comment: There is no firewall, and also there is no error indicating it is because of firewall. It just freezes, like it is stuck in an infinite loop.